# Postfix, SpamAssasin force delivery of false positives on incoming e-mail

Tags: postfix, email-server, spam, spamassassin

I'm using Postfix `2.11.3` and SpamAssasin version `3.4.0` to handle e-mail for a domain. I have several incoming messages that are marked as spam and that ended up in the hold queue.

I inspected by hand the messages and figured it that they are not spam.

How do I force local delivery of the messages wrongly marked as spam?

The mailboxes are hosted on the same server (and virtual domain) as the handling server.

I tried requeueing the message (`postsuper -r ${MSG_ID}`), but the message ended up again in the hold queue.